# ionic cannot run app in android studio missing config and showing unresolved libraries

Tags: android, ionic-framework

i'm using ionic and i try to run my app in android studio. On Ios everything is working fine but android studio is always saying please add configuration. I actually have no idea how to add a configuration. Also my project contains three packages. I'm building my project with the following commands:

ionic build
npx cap sync
npx cap open android

Also android studio cannot resolve some libraries.

Please find attached a screenshot of the errors i have mentioned above:

thank you
[image: unresolved libraries]

[image: missing config]

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue, and I think it was a few problems compounded.  It looks like you shouldn't have to add configurations manually, so if the "app" configuration doesn't appear automatically then something is wrong.  I ran

`ionic cap build android`

which built everything and launched android studio.  If that doesn't fix it, you might be missing some sdks.  Try running this command from your android folder.

`./gradlew assembleDebug`

Mine complained about missing a specific version of the android sdk which I had to install with the android studio sdk manager. Then I relaunched android studio, and the "app" configuration was there.